# Exact position of a Java graphic element on a screen?

Tags: java, user-interface, screen, label, awt

I have a question. In Java, how do you get the screen position of a graphic element, let's say a Label? If I use getBounds, I'm getting the relative position inside the container, not the exact position of the screen. I would kindly appreciate if someone can help me out here...thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `Component.getLocationOnScreen()`.